# Dropdownlist Control Array having same Value

Tags: c#, controls

I have an array of Dropdownlist controls. When I set the selected value of one it sets them for all of them. What am I doing wrong?

```
Dropdownlist[] _ddl = new Dropdownlist[7];

for(int i=0;i<=6;i++)
{
    _dll[i] = new Dropdownlist();
    _dll[i].ID = "dropdown" + i;
    _ddl[i].AutoPostBack = true;
    _ddl[i].Items.AddRange(GradeLevels);
    if (Grade == "A")
    _ddl[i].Items.FindByValue("A").Selected = true;

}
```

Comment: You are adding same item to all dropdowns and selecting item with same criteria so it would select same item for all dropdown. also you are looping index 0 through 6 which mean you must have array of size 7 but you have size 6 so you must be getting index out of bound exception

Comment: ok. How do I fix it. BTW I edit the code to make it correct.

Comment: It is not clear that index of what drop down you want to set

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use

```
    String Grade = "A";
    string[] GradeLevels = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };
    DropDownList _ddl = new DropDownList();
    _ddl.AutoPostBack=true;
    for (int i = 0; i < GradeLevels.Length; i++)
    {
        _ddl.Items.Add(new ListItem(GradeLevels[i], GradeLevels[i]));
    }
        _ddl.Items.FindByValue(Grade).Selected = true;
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(_ddl);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Dropdownlist[] _ddl = new Dropdownlist[6];

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        _dll[i] = new Dropdownlist();
        _dll[i].ID = "dropdown" + i;
        _ddl[i].AutoPostBack = true;
        _ddl[i].Items.AddRange(GradeLevels);       
    }

    // set the selected item in the first list
    if (Grade == "A")
        _ddl[0].Items.FindByValue("A").Selected = true;
```

Comment: It works?       (I fixed the loop variable and moved the setting of the selected item outside the loop)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create clone copies of your GradeLevels object and add to each Dropdownlist a different copy of that object.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I figured it out using this.

http://leekelleher.com/2008/11/24/populating-multiple-dropdownlist-controls-with-generic-listitem-array/